# jQuery get list from C# code behide

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have C# code behide to return a list of string:

```
public List<string> GoStatusList { get {    return GetStatusList(); } }
```

Can I use it in jQuery, probably something like:

```
var statusList = $('#<%=GoStatusList %>');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<string> GoStatusList { get {    return GetStatusList(); } }
```

`var statusList = $('#<%=GoStatusList %>');` // Will not give you the list but will give you the type of list.

Instead In c# code write :

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "getList", 
"GetStatusList ([" + string.Join(",",GoStatusList ) +"]);", true);
```

in Javascript you can do like :

```
   function GetStatusList (GoStatusList)
    {
    // logic here 
               var data = GoStatusList.d; // check as per your application
                $.each(data , function(index, item) {
                    alert(item);//Here you will get items of your list
                });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please advise how jQuery loop through the 'GoStatusList'?

Comment: It seems the GoStatusList I got from jQuery is just a string "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Comment: Thanks! I works! Should use '' instead of [] anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make GoStatusList function in jquery and call this function from code behind like this

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "",GoStatusList()  , true);
```

OR

`ScriptManager.registerstartupscript(this, this.GetType(), "",GoStatusList()  , true);`

Hope this helps you